# Compare two strings is not working properly in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

Here is my Javascript function where I'm comparing two strings one value receive as a function parameter and another one is fetching from json which is coming from Spring response.

But I'm very Surprise I'm not able to compare two strings with `===` and `==`, I can see the values in debugger.

I'm caling my function from my HTML code:

```
<textarea onblur="searchProduct(this.value)"></textarea >
```

Javascript:

```
function searchProduct(value)
{
    alert(value);
    for (i in allProducts) {
        console.log(allProducts[0].productName);
        var tempProductName=allProducts[i].productName;
            alert(tempProductName.toString() == value.toString());
        // checks product name is present or not
        if( tempProductName.toString() === value.toString()){
//          setting other values details of products
                    $('#description').val(allProducts[i].productDescription);
                    $('.cost').val(allProducts[i].unitPrice);
        }//if

        }
}//searchProduct
```

**allProducts:** response from spring

> [{"productId":3,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P1name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":760.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":148.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":4,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P2name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":150.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":5,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P3name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":6,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P4name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":7,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P5name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":8,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P6name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":9,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P7name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":10,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P8name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":11,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P9name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":12,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P9name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":13,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P9name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":14,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P9name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":15,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P9name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"},{"productId":16,"sku":"QTY","vendorProductId":"v1","productName":"P10name","productDescription":"p1 desc","supplierId":"s1","categoryId":"c","quantityPerUnit":1.0,"unitPrice":1.0,"msrp":1.0,"availableSize":40.0,"availableColors":"black,blue","size":40.0,"color":"white","discount":0.0,"unitWeight":1.0,"unitsInStock":1000.0,"unitsOnOrder":500.0,"reorderLevel":150.0,"productAvailable":"Y","discountAvailable":"N","currentOrder":0.0,"pictureURL":"Picture path","ranking":10,"note":"Sample Notes","smsNotification":"N","productExpiryDate":null,"productDeleted":null,"alertExpiryDate":null,"idsku":"IDSKU1"}]

Comment: Why not use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)?

Comment: @hindmost, I want to compare it, could you please post your answer

Comment: I've executed your code in my js console in this way: searchProduct("P1name"); The first result was "true". Please can you write a better description for your problem?

Comment: In my case it always return false. :(

Comment: Update my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS string comparison is case sensitive, and you probably need case insensitive one, for example:

```
tempProductName.toUpperCase() === value.toUpperCase()
```

instead of:

```
tempProductName.toString() === value.toString()
```

You don't need `toString()` anyway, because the field is already a string.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, this should work.

Try changing the iterator - `for..in` is for iterating over objects (ie. dictionaries). To iterate over an array, use either a regular `for` or a `forEach`:

```
function searchProduct(value) {
  allProducts
    .filter(function(product) {
      return product[productName] === value
    })
    .forEach(function(product) {
      $('#description').val(product.productDescription);
      $('.cost').val(product.unitPrice);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own string comparing method with `indexOf` and `length`:

```
String.prototype.equals = function (str2) {
    return this.indexOf(str2) == 0 && this.length == str2.length;
}
```

Or a more "PHP" style like method:

```
function string_compare (str1, str2) {
   return str1.indexOf(str2) == 0 && str1.length == str2.length;
}
```

Comment: Do not extend the prototype like the 1st example - it's very, very bad practice. Instead make a separate function, like the 2nd example!

Comment: @bcherny Can you explain why it's a bad practice?

Comment: It can cause hard to track down issues when you are using your script in combination with other libraries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice, http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/, etc.